# Json BaseAdapter

Tags: android, json, baseadapter

i try to parse json from url and show items  listview(images and text) . i have one problem  adapter add  same items on listview.  on my URl i have 20 items
At first it seems good but when try to scroll list ,records is the same  (more specifically, the records of which were originally list)
meybe my problem is BaseAdapter  and this is a my code

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
public ViewHolder holder;

public ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> itemList;
private int screenSize;
MainActivity main;

public BRIgeAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d,
        int screenSize) {
    this.activity = a;
    this.data = d;
    this.screenSize = screenSize;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        main = new MainActivity();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        holder.journal = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);
        holder.statId = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);

        holder.smallDescription1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription1);
        holder.DateTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
        holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.smallthumb);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        itemList = data.get(position);


        holder.journal.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_journal));
        // holder.DateTime.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate));
        holder.statId.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_statID));
        holder.smallDescription1.setText(itemList
                .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));
        holder.journal.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

        String titleString = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_title);

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 11, 20);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        // DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

        String DateTime = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate);
        DateTime = date;

        holder.DateTime.setText(DateTime);

        holder.thumb_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        holder.title.setText(titleString);
        holder.title.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

        holder.title.setLineSpacing(2, 1.2f);
        holder.description.setLineSpacing(2, 1.2f);

        if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
            holder.description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            holder.description.setText(itemList
                    .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));

        holder.description.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_image),
                holder.thumb_image);

    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView journal, title, description, smallDescription1,
            DateTime, statId;
    ImageView thumb_image;
}
```

if anyone know solution my problem please  help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem is in creating of holder ..

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    main = new MainActivity();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    holder.journal = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);
    holder.statId = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);

    holder.smallDescription1 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription1);
    holder.DateTime = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
    holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallthumb);
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
    holder.description = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
```

}else{
holder=convertview.getTag();
}
        itemList = data.get(position);

```
    holder.journal.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_journal));
    // holder.DateTime.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate));
    holder.statId.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_statID));
    holder.smallDescription1.setText(itemList
            .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));
    holder.journal.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    String titleString = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_title);

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 11, 20);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    // DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

    String DateTime = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate);
    DateTime = date;

    holder.DateTime.setText(DateTime);

    holder.thumb_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    holder.title.setText(titleString);
    holder.title.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    holder.title.setLineSpacing(2, 1.2f);
    holder.description.setLineSpacing(2, 1.2f);

    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
        holder.description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        holder.description.setText(itemList
                .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));

    holder.description.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_image),
            holder.thumb_image);

}
return convertView;
```

}

Comment: As I have mentioned in above code..if convertview is null then create holder object by new operator and if convertview is not null then get holder from convertview  holder=convertview.getTag();

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on your getView method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    main = new MainActivity();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    holder.journal = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);
    holder.statId = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);

    holder.smallDescription1 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription1);
    holder.DateTime = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
    holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallthumb);
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
    holder.description = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

 }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag()

    itemList = data.get(position);


    holder.journal.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_journal));
    // holder.DateTime.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate));
    holder.statId.setText(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_statID));
    holder.smallDescription1.setText(itemList
            .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));
    holder.journal.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    String titleString = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_title);

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 11, 20);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    // DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

    String DateTime = itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_pubDate);
    DateTime = date;

    holder.DateTime.setText(DateTime);

    holder.thumb_image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    holder.title.setText(titleString);
    holder.title.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    holder.title.setLineSpacing(2, 1.2f);
    holder.description.setLineSpacing(2, 1.2f);

    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
        holder.description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        holder.description.setText(itemList
                .get(MainActivity.KEY_description));

    holder.description.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(itemList.get(MainActivity.KEY_image),
            holder.thumb_image);

}
return convertView;
}
```

Also if MainActivity is in fact and android Activity please don't instantiate it for every item of your list

Comment: what is a solution for your option ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at your getView() function Because you said if (convertView==null) and you did everything at there but if convertview not null everything look similar so you should add else condition I hope its give you idea

Comment: i changed and it wokting perfect but  my listview's scrolling is lag on large size screen resolution(for example nexus 7) also my last code(witch had a problem json) listview 's scroll was not be lag. i have not idea what is a problem.